# Secure RESTful API via HTTP(S): How to deal with the certificate host check without host name (only IP address)?

Tags: rest, security, http, ssl, https

For implementing a RESTful API via HTTP I need a way to secure communication (encryption of communication, prevention of man-in-the-middle and replay attacks).

The API is supposed to be used for communication between software PC clients (Windows, Linux), smart phones, hardware clients on the one hand and an embedded device (the server) on the other hand.

If I use HTTPS with one (all embedded devices ever manufactured can use the same one I think) self-signed certificate (that clients have embedded/store somewhere) I get all the benefits I want.

Now I have got one issue:

As the embedded devices are always accessed by IP address, the client side host check for the certificate is going to fail. Whatever is written in the certificate is NOT going to be the host that answers.

E.g. with libcurl I have to disable the check via

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlEasyHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
```

This doesn't hurt too bad for self-written clients - but clients are also supposed to be written by 3rd party developers. What I find awkward now, is that 3rd parties have to know, that they have to disable the host check (and they *have to* do it...).
Also, I am not sure if disabling this check is always possible with whatever http/TLS lib that 3rd parties are using.

A certificate issued for an IP address (if even possible?!) is not an option, as the IP address can be changed by the user of the device.

Is there a way for a certificate to be "host neutral"? Or is a part of my approach incorrect and I should do something differently? Or is there nothing that can be done about it and everybody implements it like this?

Comment: A "host neutral" certificate would make certification pretty useless, don't you think? Anyway, this is a really interesting question, I'm looking forward to some answers...

Comment: @Hexaholic: In the general use case it would be useless. Agreed. But for my use case it would be just a public key container. Then I'd be alright (I think).